# Create new variable that shows the Nth placed element in a matrix (by case)

Tags: r, matrix, max, element

First off, I'm really sorry for the clumsiness of this (including the title) - I'm a newby to R. I trained on SPSS but I'm forcing myself to exclusively use R from now on.

I have a dataframe that shows the election results of each area in one year, split by party. It looks like this:

[image]

I have created a new variable that displays the winning party in each area, using the max() function (I think, again quite clumsy), like this:

```
winner = function(x, labs){
    most_votes = max(x)
    most_idx = which(x == most_votes)
    return(labs[most_idx])
}

labs = names(df1970results)[6:11]
most_votes = apply(df1970results[,6:11], 1, winner, labs = labs)
df1970results = as.data.frame(cbind(df1970results, most_votes))
```

I need another variable that tells me the second placed party in each area, but I can't find an appropriate post to tell me how to do it. Either that, or I'm not fully understanding the ones that I have read, so that I'm able to transfer it to my problem. The output of the above code is the label of the max variable (so the elements are populated with CON, LAB, LIB... in the new variable) - I wouldn't mind these being numerically coded, if that's a necessity (so 1=CON, 2=LAB...).

Could anybody show me an easy way to do this? I'm sure there's got to be an easy, newby-proof way. I'm frustrated that I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
library(data.table) #just for the fread
df1970results <- fread('http://electoralcalculus.co.uk/electdata_1970.txt')
labs = names(df1970results)[6:11]

most_votes <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df1970results[,6:11],1,function(x) labs[order(-x)])))

head(most_votes)
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
1 CON LAB LIB NAT MIN OTH
2 LAB CON LIB NAT MIN OTH
3 LAB CON LIB OTH NAT MIN
4 CON LAB LIB NAT MIN OTH
5 CON LAB LIB NAT MIN OTH
6 CON LAB LIB NAT MIN OTH
```

This will result in a data frame of the party names in descending order for each constituency, so you can use column 1 for the winner, column 2 for second place, etc.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it's worked. There was no error code but I can't see any re-organisation of the data. Is there a better way I can share the data with you? In fact, I loaded it like this:

library(data.table)
df1970results <- fread('http://www.electoralcalculus.co.uk/electdata_1970.txt')
View(df1970results)

Comment: Oh, it did do something (slow computer), but not what we wanted it to, unfortunately. I really appreciate the answer though, thanks again.

Comment: It is possible you need to transpose it `as.data.frame(t(apply(...`

Comment: Yes - found the data and the transpose solution works.  Answer amended above.  You can then `cbind` this to the original data if you wish.